# R- function %in% - different result with the same argument

Tags: r, function, arguments

I don't understand the code below :

```
Huto19952013<-seq(as.Date("1995/1/1"), as.Date("2013/12/31"), "days")
> Huto[1] %in% Huto19952013 
[1] FALSE
> Huto[1]
[1] "1995-01-01"
> "1995-01-01" %in% Huto19952013
[1] TRUE
```

Why the result is different?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you perhaps post a minimal *complete* example (i.e. with an assignment to `Huto19952013`) so that we can play with it?

Comment: It might be a date/character class issue. What is the class of `Huto[1]`?

Comment: Your last command does not return `TRUE` for your example data. I agree with @RichardScriven. Check the `class`es of your objects.

Comment: It would need to be `as.Date("1995-01-01") %in% Huto19952013`

Comment: Huto[1] is "Date", ok you're right is a problem of class. Sorry . Thank you

Comment: `grep(Huto[1], Huto19952013)` without changing the classes, but yeah the classes should match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is probably occurring:

```
Huto <- as.Date("1995-01-01")
Huto19952013 <- c("1995-01-01", "1995-02-01")
Huto[1] %in% Huto19952013 

> Huto[1] %in% Huto19952013 
[1] FALSE
> "1995-01-01"%in% Huto19952013
[1] TRUE
```

You are trying to match dates against characters.

You can make the dates characters or the characters dates:

```
> as.character(Huto[1]) %in% Huto19952013 
[1] TRUE
> Huto[1] %in% as.Date(Huto19952013 )
[1] TRUE
```